Avoid the same function being triggered repeatedly in the ViewModel when a Jetpack Compose view recomposes during view loading in Android
I'm building an Android app using Jetpack Compose. I have a view that displays user details and uses a ViewModel to manage the data. The user details are fetched from a service or database. However, the fetch call is triggered unnecessarily every time I rotate the screen because of the configuration change. I'd like to prevent this redundant call and optimize the behavior.
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ....) {
   ....
   ....
   composable("userDetails") {
      UserDetailsScreen(userUrl = userUrl)
   }
}

@Composable
fun UserDetailsScreen(
    userUrl: String,
    viewModel: UserDetailsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    LaunchedEffect(userUrl) {
       viewModel.fetchUserDetails(userUrl) // <==
       /* How to prevent the above call getting triggered unnecessarily every time 
          I rotate the screen because of the configuration change? */
    }
    val userDetailsState by viewModel.userDetailsState.collectAsState()
}

@HiltViewModel
class UserDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val usersRepository: UsersRepository): ViewModel() {
   .....
   fun fetchUserDetails(url: String) { 
      viewModelScope.launch {
         usersRepository.fetchUserDetails(url).collect { 
            ......
         }
      }
   }
}


You are not supposed to call fetching data using LaunchedEffect because it will trigger when screen orientation changes. you must use flow inside the ViewModel so that it can survive the configuration changes and Observe Flow from the Viewmodel.

Just like when using Views the whole activity is recreated so all the UI is recreated too making the use of LaunchedEffect here pointless for that purpose. ignoring config changes on the activity would stop it from calling again but any UI logic you may have to handle different orientations would not work

To optimize the behavior of your UserDetailsViewModel and prevent unnecessary data fetching on configuration changes like screen rotations in your app, you can leverage the ViewModel's lifecycle. Since ViewModels survive configuration changes, you can check if the data has already been loaded before making another fetch call. Here's how you can adjust your ViewModel and composable function to achieve this:
ViewModel Changes
First, you'll want to modify your ViewModel to include logic that checks whether the user details have already been fetched and avoid refetching if that's the case:
@HiltViewModel
class UserDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val usersRepository: UsersRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private var isDataLoaded = false
    private var lastUrl: String? = null

    val userDetailsState = MutableStateFlow<UserDetails?>(null) // Assuming UserDetails is your data class

    fun fetchUserDetails(url: String) {
        // Only fetch data if it hasn't been loaded or if the URL has changed
        if (!isDataLoaded || lastUrl != url) {
            lastUrl = url
            viewModelScope.launch {
                usersRepository.fetchUserDetails(url).collect { userDetails ->
                    userDetailsState.value = userDetails
                    isDataLoaded = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Composable Function Changes
In your UserDetailsScreen composable, you don't need to make any changes because it correctly initializes the ViewModel and calls fetchUserDetails within a LaunchedEffect, which is tied to the userUrl. The optimization to prevent unnecessary fetches is handled within the ViewModel itself.
This approach ensures that your app only fetches data when necessary and is more efficient in handling configuration changes like screen rotations.
EDIT:
If you would like to use it inside the composable rather than view model, then you should use the rememberSaveable to store the url:
@Composable
fun UserDetailsScreen(
    userUrl: String,
    viewModel: UserDetailsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    // Remember a key or flag indicating whether we've fetched data for this URL
    val fetchedForUrl = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    LaunchedEffect(userUrl) {
        // Only fetch if the URL has changed or on first composition
        if (fetchedForUrl.value != userUrl) {
            viewModel.fetchUserDetails(userUrl)
            // Mark as fetched for this URL
            fetchedForUrl.value = userUrl
        }
    }

    val userDetailsState by viewModel.userDetailsState.collectAsState()
    // Use userDetailsState to display your UI
}


Thanks, just curious to know whether it can be handled from the compose rather than view model?

@NaveenPrinceP I just edited my answer. This is how I would approach it using rememberSaveable.

I like the second approach, thanks
